# How to change the actual color of the selected text?

Tags: css, selection

When you select this text, you will see a blue selection field. But that's not the point of my question. After you select this text, if you are using a PC, the color of the actual text becomes white. On a mac, it stays the color it was before. That's the color I want to change.

Is there a cross-browser solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `::selection` pseudo-selector:

```
::selection {
    background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
​
::-moz-selection {
    background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}​
```

Due to [parsing rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aselection), you need to duplicate your CSS and re-prefix it:

> Gecko is the only engine requiring the prefix. *Due to the fact that
>   the CSS parsing rules require dropping the whole rule when
>   encountering an invalid pseudo-element, two separate rules must be
>   written*: `::-moz-selection, ::selection {...}`. The rule would be
>   dropped on non-Gecko browsers as `::-moz-selection` is invalid on them.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/Hs7bQ/**

Comment: A proprietary selector needs a separate rule.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the fiddle, as you can't put both selectors in one.  -moz-selection needs to be it's own.
[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs7bQ/3/)

[Mozilla Developers ::selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aselection)